# Using "grep -c" with pipes to get a count

Tags: count, grep, pipe

I want to get a count of matches with grep.
grep -c works fine with one pattern.
But when I pipe (|) a second pattern, it returns nothing.

Here is an example:

File test with contents:

```
A C
A A
A B
A B C
```

I run the command:

```
>grep A test
    A C
    A A
    A B
    A B C
```

I run the command:

```
>grep -c A test
    4
```

I run the command:

```
>grep A test | grep B
A B
A B C
```

I run the command:

```
grep -c A test | grep B
```

returns nothing

How can I get a count of 2 for the second example?

thank you

Answer (score 1):

`grep -c A test` outputs `4`. The result of searching for rows that match `B` in a text consisting of `4` is unsurprisingly empty.

Instead, you want to count at the last step:

```
grep A test | grep -c B
```

Here, the first command filters the rows down to only those that have `A`, then the second command filters *those* rows into those that contain `B`, finally counting them.

Comment: but with this sample file there's no reason to `grep A test | grep -c B` because all lines containing A also contain B, just `grep -c B test` is enough

Comment: @phuclv Yes, in this example that is true. But that would not have resolved OP's confusion about why they are getting a result they did not expect. I also expect this is not their real data, so I try to keep the answer general.

Answer (score 1):

The role of the pipe command is to use the result of the previous command as the input of the next command, you should use `grep A test | grep -c B`